# get value of array of arrays in php

Tags: php

So, let's assume I am not using php 5.4 because I tried

```
$results[0][0]
```

and it did not work.  My array $results is an array of arrays and I want to return the first value of the first array.  How would I do this without doing the above, because it doesn't work.

Comment: It helps if you show the contents of the array by using var_dump

Comment: I was basically just trying to do what var_dump does (was trying to see the contents of my array), thanks for help!

Comment: Using `$results[0][0]` doesn't require PHP >= 5.4.0, it will work with any version of PHP.... as long as you have keys 0 and 0

Comment: Yeah, I assumed keys were 0,1,2,3.. etc but they were different.

Comment: Just show us your output of: `print_r($yourArray);`

Comment: @BrianJ Maybe you have associative arrays, so they're not numbered like that.

Answer (score 0):

Let assume that your array looks like this

```
$results = array(
        'k1'=>array(
            'k1.1'=>'v1.1',
            'k1.2'=>'v1.2',
            'k1.3'=>'v1.3',
        ),
        'k2'=>array(
            'k2.1'=>'v2.1',
            'k2.2'=>'v2.2',
            'k2.3'=>'v2.3',
        ),
    );
```

Then if you need to get first value of the first array this should help

```
$results[key($results)][key($results[key($results)])];
```

Looks weird :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreach function

```
foreach($result as $resk => $resv ){
    $i = 1;
    foreach($resv as $rk => $rv ){
       if($i == 1){
          echo  $rv;
       }
       $i++;
    }
}
```